# Parsing Google Visualization data with R

Tags: r, google-visualization

Is there a library for parsing a [Google Visualization Data](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews?hl=en) structure to R.

The data will come in a json format that can be converted with jsonlite, the issue is from there to an R structure.

It's something like this (in json):

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
   {
     cols: [{id: 'task', label: 'Employee Name', type: 'string'},
            {id: 'startDate', label: 'Start Date', type: 'date'}],
     rows: [{c:[{v: 'Mike'}, {v: new Date(2008, 1, 28), f:'February 28, 2008'}]},
            {c:[{v: 'Bob'}, {v: new Date(2007, 5, 1)}]},
            {c:[{v: 'Alice'}, {v: new Date(2006, 7, 16)}]},
            {c:[{v: 'Frank'}, {v: new Date(2007, 11, 28)}]},
            {c:[{v: 'Floyd'}, {v: new Date(2005, 3, 13)}]},
            {c:[{v: 'Fritz'}, {v: new Date(2011, 6, 1)}]}
           ]
   }
)
```

Comment: you might want to check out the [googleVis package](https://github.com/mages/googleVis)